# gradient descent relaxation dynamics of a Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, gradient-descent, euler-lagrange-equation

To minimize the functional $\int{L(u)}dx$, where L=$u_x^2-u^2$. Though its Euler-Lagrange equation is easy to solve, I want to turn it into solving a gradient descent problem as a general method, for the Euler-Lagrange will be hard to solve if the functional is replaced with a complicated one. I propose to solve the gradient descent dynamics $u’(t)=-\delta{L}/\delta{u}$, just a relaxation dynamics of the original Euler-Lagrange statics. I hope, as t goes to inf, the  solution to this gradient descent dynamics coincides with that to the original Euler-Lagrange eq. However, the solution is diverged for the obvious reason that $-u^2$ is concave down in u. How to resolve/rewrite this relaxation dynamics for my purpose?

Comment: Hi again @feynman and happy New Year ! If I understand you well, you want to enforce the equation of motion to be $u'=-\frac{\delta L}{\delta u}$ for the harmonic oscillator, right ? In that case, you cannot use the same Lagrangian, because $\frac{\delta}{\delta u}(u'^2-u^2) = 2u''-2u\neq-u'$ for an harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Oops, it should be $-2u''-2u$.

Comment: @Abezhiko happy new year! Sorry for the confusion, but my ' denotes time derivative, not d/dx